# Send a list to django within an ajax GET request

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I found a lot of posts here and outside talking about this problem but with `POST` request.

**THIS IS THE PROBLEM**: I have a list in my javascript and I need to send that list to django view as argument.

**Javascript**

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "myMethod",
    type: "GET",
    data: {"par1":par1,"par2":par2,"list":list},
    cache: false,
    success: function(d){
      // DO SOMETHING
    }
}
```

**Python** 
**code** **(views.py)**

```py
def myMethod(request):
    par1 = request.GET.get('par1')
    par1 = request.GET.get('par2')
    list = request.GET.get('list') # DON'T WORK
    #OR
    list = request.GET.getlist('list') # DON'T WORK
    #OR
    list = request.GET.getlist('list[]') # DON'T WORK
    result = DO_SOMETHING(par1,par2,list)
    return result
```

I tried three ways that I found in other posts but none was working.

Comment: You haven't identified what the problem is. Also what are `par1-par3` ?

Comment: More importantly, what is `list` here, Django has a specific format for lists that can be gotten with `getlist()`

Comment: @charlietfl I am sorry I thought this was clear, see  **THIS IS THE PROBLEM**

Comment: @farhawa clear as mud. You haven't identified if request is being made or any basic troubleshooting steps that would help. How would we know whether you are having server side or client side problems ... or both. Not to mention showing us numerous undefined variables

Comment: Can you show the contents of request.GET?

Comment: @charlietfl I need to send a list from javascript to django view by ajax GET request. That's my problem. Thank you anyway

Comment: in browser dev tools is request being made? What is status? You aren't trying to narrow down anything regarding server vs client code. Let alone we don't know if your variables are defined or what they are

Comment: The request have been made and here is no error, just I get an empty list in python side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you join the list before posting and the split it in your django view?

**Javascript**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "myMethod",
    type: "GET",
    data: {"par1":par1,"par2":par2,"list":list.join("-and-")},
    cache: false,
    success: function(d){
      // DO SOMETHING
    }
}
```

**Python code (views.py)**

```
def myMethod(request):
    par1 = request.GET.get('par1')
    par1 = request.GET.get('par2')
    list = request.GET.get('list').split('-and-')

    result = DO_SOMETHING(par1,par2,list)
    return result
```